# Overlaying point data with NDVI layer with raster output (not graph)

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, overlay, ndvi

I have point data, which are animal burrows, and a NDVI raster layer that shows plant productivity. I want to overlay these layers and determine if vegetation productivity is higher close to burrows (or in a certain radius around burrows). The output must be a raster and not a correlation graph, something like this image (Bonachela et al., 2015): [image: model showing productivity] 
showing how productivity changes close to burrows and the further you move away from burrows. Can this be done with QGIS, R or another program?

Comment: Anyone that knows how to do this and can help me? It's rather urgent please.